# Ajax call api time

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, jquery

Hi I'm tring to use an api to get time and data but in log appear always error 403 forbidden. Api:https://www.mashape.com/parsify/format#!endpoint-Phone-Number.
Is there an ajax call error?

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',

headers: {"X-Mashape-Authorization": "SEK2****7Egqx******hshVCG"},


async:false,
//dataType: "jsonp",
url: 'https://parsify-format.p.mashape.com/api/format/time?value=1362446014869&lang=it',
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 time_now=data;
},
error: function(data) {
  console.log("ko" );
}

});
```

Comment: Their [doc](https://www.mashape.com/docs/consume/javascript) shows how to add the `X-Mashape-Authorization`, do you have any particular reason to try another approach?

Comment: Link has changed. It is now: https://market.mashape.com/parsify/format#time

Answer (score 0):

A 403 is most likely caused by either the site not getting correct authorization, or cross domain ajax.

If you're testing locally, cross domain ajax is blocked in some browsers, most notably chrome.